# Word mailmerge with Aspose from C# application and 2 tables

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I have a C# application where I use ASPOSE to execute a mail merge with a Word document as the template.  The word document has a table in it with 2 rows.

The first row has {MERGEFIELD TableStart:Heading} in cell 1 and {MERGEFIELD TableEnd:Heading} in cell 5.

The second row has {MERGEFILED TableStart:Parcels} in cell 1 and {MERGEFIELD TableEnd:Parcels} in cell 5.

The application builds 3 DataTable objects.  The objects are called dt, tableHeader, and tableData.

Once the objects have been populated, I execute this code:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.Tables.Add(tableHeader);
dataSet.Tables.Add(tableData);
dataSet.Relations.Add(tableHeader.Columns["h_SBL"], tableData.Columns["t_SBL"]);
template.MailMerge.Execute(dt);
template.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(dataSet);
template.Save(outStream, Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Docx);
```

This is what the resulting document looks like:

[image]

In the image, the rows where Town and S.D. appear are in the Header table (row 1) of the word template document and the rows where the Item No: appear are in the Parcels table (row 2) of the word template document.

So right now, the process generates header row, header row, parcel row, parcel row.

I need to have the resulting document have a header row, a parcels row, a header row, a parcels row.

How would I accomplish this?

UPDATE: I am inserting an image of my word template.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should build your template from two rows. Like this:
[image]

Then you can fill such template using the following code:

```cs
DataTable data = new DataTable("tblEmployerDetails");
data.Columns.Add("EmployerName");
data.Columns.Add("EmployerAddress");
data.Columns.Add("EmployerIndustry");
data.Rows.Add("John Dou", "Unknown city, Unknown street", "Unknown");
data.Rows.Add("James Bond", "85 Albert Embankment in Vauxhall, London", "Spy");

Document doc = new Document(@"C:\Temp\in.docx");
// Instruct Aspose.Words to remove empty paragraphs after executing mail merge.
doc.MailMerge.CleanupOptions = MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveEmptyParagraphs;
doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(data);
doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
```

Since `MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveEmptyParagraphs` clean up optionis specified, the empty paragraphs which will be produced by paragraphs with `TableStart` and `TableEnd` merge fields will be removed and tables will be concatenated in the output document. The output will look like this:
[image]

UPDATE: In your case, your template can look like this:
[image]
And you can use a one table as a data source.

Comment: Not exactly what I need.  What if I wanted the Header for John Dou to read "EMPLOYER DETAILS for John Dou" and have a Header for James Bond that reads "EMPLOYER DETAILS for James Bond"?

Comment: In this case you can simply move the header row inside the region and put a merge field into the `EMPLOYER DETAILS` row.

Comment: Alexey: I'm not sure I understand what you are implying.  I have added an image which shows how my word template is constructed.  You can see where each of my merge fields are set up as well as the TableStart:Header / TableEnd:Header in row 1 and the TableStart:Parcels / TableEnd:Parcels in row 2.  There is an ASPOSE requirement of the TableStart/TableEnd being in the same row which I was running up against which is why I ended up with this layout.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Yes, you are right, `TableStart` and `TableEnd` merge fields must be in the same row if they are in the table. But you are free to put them outside the table as in my example so the whole table is repeated as a region.

Comment: Ah!  I didn't realize that the TableStart and TabelEnd could be outside of a table.  This worked perfectly!  Thank you very much.