# Word Mail Merge with ASPOSE repeats header in table for all data rows

Tags: mailmerge, aspose.words, docx-mailmerge

I have a C# MVC .NET application which uses ASPOSE to execute a mail merge.  I have a table defined in the word document like this:
[image]

I have the first row of the table defined as Repeat Heder Rows, as you can see in the image where Layout -> Data -> Repeat Header Rows is turned on when the fields in the first table row are selected.

When I run my application, and the mail merge executes, the resulting document looks like the following:

[image]

As you can see, the header information is being repeated for each dataset record.  How do I get the heading to only print once at the start of the table?  And how do I set this up so that if there are enough records in the dataset to force additional pages to be generated, to have the header generated at the start of each page.

This is the code that I use to generate the document:

```
Aspose.Words.Document masterTemplate = new Aspose.Words.Document(masterFilePath);
masterTemplate.FieldOptions.BarcodeGenerator = new CustomBarcodeGenerator();                    
masterTemplate.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(dtMasterPetition);
masterTemplate.MailMerge.Execute(new string[] { "County",                                                                    
    "CaptionPetitioner",                                                                    
    "CaptionRespondent",                                                                     
    "Jurisdiction",                                                                     
    "IndexNo",                                                                     
    "TaxYear",                                                                     
    "ReturnDay",                                                                    
    "ReturnMonthYear",                                                                    
    "PetitionDate",                                                                    
    "FirmName",                                                                    
    "RespondentAddress1",                                                                    
    "RespondentAddress2",                                                                    
    "AlsoServeTitle",                                                                    
    "AlsoServeJurisdiction",                                                                    
    "AlsoServeAddress",                                                                    
    "AlsoServeCityStateZip",                                                                    
    "MPQRCode",                                                                    
    "FileAndSuffix",                                                                    
    "Attorney"}, 
new string[] { MailMergeData.PropCounty,                                                           
    MailMergeData.CaptionPetitioner,                                                           
    MailMergeData.CaptionRespondent,                                                           
    MailMergeData.Jurisdiction,                                                           
    MailMergeData.IndexNo,                                                           
    MailMergeData.TaxYear,                                                           
    MailMergeData.ReturnDay,                                                          
    MailMergeData.ReturnMonthYear,                                                          
    MailMergeData.PetitionDate,                                                          
    MailMergeData.FirmName,                                                          
    MailMergeData.RespondentAddress1,                                                          
    MailMergeData.RespondentAddress2,                                                          
    MailMergeData.AlsoServeTitle,                                                          
    MailMergeData.AlsoServeJurisdiction,                                                          
    MailMergeData.AlsoServeAddress,                                                          
    MailMergeData.AlsoServeCityStateZip,                                                          
    oMPQRCode.ToString(),
    FileAndSuffix,
    sAttorney});
                
MemoryStream masterpetitionMemory = new MemoryStream();
masterTemplate.Save(masterpetitionMemory, Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Pdf);
docs.Add(masterpetitionMemory);
PdfFileEditor oEditor = new PdfFileEditor();
oEditor.Concatenate(docs.ToArray(), outStream);
outStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

string GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
Aspose.Pdf.Document pdfDocument = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(outStream);
fileName = fileName + "_" + GUID + ".pdf";
pdfDocument.Save(fileName);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your template whole table is enclosed into `TableStart/EableEnd` merge fields, So the whole table is repeated for each record in your data source. To get the expected output, you should defile header row in a separate table like described here:
[Word mailmerge with Aspose from C# application and 2 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77686606/word-mailmerge-with-aspose-from-c-sharp-application-and-2-tables)

Comment: I don't understand how to implement a 2-table solution, as you suggest.

Comment: You should define the repeatable header in a separate table, then enclose two rows table into TableStart/TableEnd as described in the above link. If you still encounter difficulties, please post your question in [Aspose.Words support forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8/) and attach your template, sample data and expected output documents.

Comment: Alexey: I was able to get this to work by adding a second table to my template.  Then, in my c# application, I am now using DataSet instead of DataTable and I am populating data in DataSet.Table[0] and DataSet.Table[1].  And then, in the code, I set a relationship between the two tables.  I have the document generating as needed.  Thanks!